# CS50P PSET3: Why is my code failing check50 for the grocery problem?

Tags: python, cs50

The problem set I am trying to solve: [CS50P 2022 psets/3/grocery/](https://cs50.harvard.edu/python/2022/psets/3/grocery/)

The code I wrote:

```
# Syntax of dict = {'key': value}
mydict = {}

# Infinite loop with break
while True:
    try:
        item = input().upper()
        # Search if item matches a key inside the dict
        if item in mydict:
            mydict[item] = mydict[item] + 1
        else:
            mydict[item] = 1
    except EOFError:
        for i in mydict:
            print(mydict[i], i)
        break
```

The check50 results:

```
Results for cs50/problems/2022/python/grocery generated by check50 v3.3.7
:) grocery.py exists
:) input of EOF halts program
:) input of "apple" and "banana" yields "1 APPLE 1 BANANA"
:) input of "strawberry" and "strawberry" yields "2 STRAWBERRY"
:) input of "mango", "sugar", and "mango" yields "2 MANGO 1 SUGAR"
:( input of "tortilla" and "sweet potato" yields "1 SWEET POTATO 1 TORTILLA"
    expected "1 SWEET POTATO...", not "\n\n1 TORTILLA..."
```

As you can see above, check50 is failing:

```
:( input of "tortilla" and "sweet potato" yields "1 SWEET POTATO 1 TORTILLA"
    expected "1 SWEET POTATO...", not "\n\n1 TORTILLA..."
```

But when I run python grocery.py the result seems to match the expected outcome:

```
tortilla
sweet potato
1 TORTILLA
1 SWEET POTATO
```

I am having trouble understanding where I made the mistake. Please help.

Comment: One of the requirements is you print the output in alphabetical order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake was that the dict wasn't ordered properly. I solved that by importing **OrderedDict** method from *collections* class. Here's the code I added in the except statement:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

...

while True:
    try:
        ...
    except EOFError:
        # https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict 
        mydict = OrderedDict(sorted(mydict.items(), key=lambda t: t[0]))
        ...
```

Answer (score 1):

I think we have to print Grocery list in alphabetical order,
so for printing items I use this:

```
for key,value in sorted(dict.items()):
                print(value,key)
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not find the exact problem of this code, but you can try to format your string before adding it to your dictionary. Python split method is really powerful for that. Maybe CS50 tries some weird combination to simulate a bad user.
I would do something like that:

```
s=input()
t=s.split()
ret=""
n=len(t)
for k in range(n-1):
    ret+=f"{t[k].upper()} ".format(t[k].upper())
ret+=t[-1].upper()
```

And then put ret in your dic. This way, you have a proper string, without extra space, tab or end of line... No idea if it works, let me know !

Answer (score 0):

```
list_str=[]

while True:
    try:
        value=input()
        list_str.append(value)
    except EOFError:
        break

new_list=list(set(list_str))
for i in new_list:
    print(f"{list_str.count(i)} {i.upper()}")
```

Comment: It's probably the most inefficient way of solving this problem, especially compared to OP's original solution in this old post, which has only minor issue (output ordering). Downvote mine: while this solves the problem, the alg. complexity of this is O(n**2) instead of original O(n logn).

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Answer (score 0):

```
grocery_list = []

while True:

    try:
        items = input().upper()
        grocery_list.append(items)
    except EOFError:
        print()
        break

x = set(grocery_list)
final = sorted(x)

for item in final:
    count = grocery_list.count(item)
    print(count, item)
```